# Custom execution planner

Tags: java, neo4j

Is there any way to develop a custom execution planner for queries?

As execution plan I refer to
https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/execution-plans/

I want to develop an execution planner to modify the order with which match clauses are executed.
For example, is the query only specifies a list of edges, I would like to choose the order with which edges are matched.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to plug in your own planner implementation.

However, since the code is [open source](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j), you could always fork the repo and modify the planner yourself.

Comment: Thank you.So now the question is: is there any documentation that can help me in modifying the source code?

Comment: [This page](https://neo4j.com/developer/?ref=open-source) is a starting point for resources. You can also ask questions [here](http://community.neo4j.com).